# could anyone explain what does "errorStatus.prettyPrint()" in pysnmp mean?

Tags: pysnmp

I'm not able to understand what does "errorStatus.prettyPrint()" in pysnmp mean. Could anyone explain in a simple language? currently I'm working on pysnmp, so I need to understand what does this mean

Answer (score 0):

SNMP packet contains the `error-status` integer field that is used by SNMP agent to communicate certain class of errors, occurred when processing request, back to SNMP manager. The errors are [enumerated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1905) so that each integer value has definite semantics. That is:

```
             error-status            -- sometimes ignored
                 INTEGER {
                     noError(0),
                     tooBig(1),
                     noSuchName(2),   -- for proxy compatibility
                     badValue(3),     -- for proxy compatibility
                     readOnly(4),     -- for proxy compatibility
                     genErr(5),
                     ...
```

Note that no error is manifested by the value of 0 which evaluates to `False` in Python.

So pysnmp [errorStatus](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/current/apps/sync-command-generator.html) is just an integer, when you call `.prettyPrint()` on it, it prints out human-friendly description of enumerated error.